# Existence of a solution of a system of ODEs

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following system of ODEs,
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
x'=-x^2-xy+x\\
y'=-y^2-xy+y
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
with initial conditions $x(0)=x_0>0$ and $y(0)=y_0>0$.

I should prove that $(x(t),y(t))$ is defined for all $t\geq 0$ and that $x(t)>0$ and $y(t)>0$ for all $t\geq 0$. Any suggestion?

Comment: Idea: Adding to equalities and defining $u=x+y$ gives an explicit solution for $u$. Then subtracting them and defining $v=x-y$ gives a (not nice) solution for $v$. Finally, you might reach $x,y$ using $u,v$.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming $x\ne0$ and $y\ne0$, dividing ($1$) by $x$ and ($2$) by $y$ gives

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{x^\prime}{x}=\dfrac{y^\prime}{y}
\end{equation}

thus

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{d}{dt}\ln(x)=\dfrac{d}{dt}\ln(y)
\end{equation}

thus

\begin{equation}
x(t)=c_1y(t)
\end{equation}

So equation ($2$) becomes

\begin{equation}
y^\prime-y=-(1+c_1)y^2
\end{equation}

which is an easy Bernoulli equation.

Solving the Bernoulli equation gives

\begin{align}
x(t)&=\dfrac{c_1}{c_2e^{-t}+c_1+1}\\
y(t)&=\dfrac{1}{c_2e^{-t}+c_1+1}
\end{align}

So $x(0)=\dfrac{c_1}{c_1+c_2+1}>0$ and $y(0)=\dfrac{1}{c_1+c_2+1}>0$.

So we know $1+c_1+c_2>0$ and $c_1>0$ and that $x(t)>0,y(t)>0$ for all $t$.

Proceeding upon an assumption that neither $x(t)$ nor $y(t)$ is ever $0$ we do obtain solutions for which that is true.

This leaves open the question whether there is some other solution to the system for which that is false (other than the obvious $x(t)=y(t)=0$).

Note that

\begin{equation}
y^\prime=f(x,y)=-y^2-xy+y
\end{equation}

is continuous on a neighborhood of every $(t_0,y_0)$ and that

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}=-2y-x+1
\end{equation}

is also continuous on a neighborhood of every $(t_0,y_0)$ so there is a unique solution for equation ($2$) containing each $(t_0,y_0)$, in this particular case at $(0,y_0)$. The same argument goes for the equation ($1$). There is a unique equation for ($1$) containing $(0,x_0)$.

Comment: To do that, isn't it necessary to *first* show that $x$ never cancels (i.e., pretty much that $x(t)>0$ for all $t$)?

Comment: I'll edit to add that assumption, which I failed to make explicit. But the result follows upon that assumption.

Comment: PS: It's storming here so I may lose my satellite internet connection.

Comment: That assumption is essentially half of the question, though... "I should prove that $(x(t),y(t))$ is defined for all $t\geq 0$ and that $x(t)>0$ and $y(t)>0$ for all $t\geq 0$."

Comment: The solution you find is a *logistic* function, that is one of the most fundamental is different sort of models ; this is not surprising, see for example (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) where one finds a differential equation for this logistic function which has some connections with the differential system of this question.

Comment: Since I was not sure you understood the reasoning behind the uniqueness of the solution, I have added additional information.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales You can absolutely safely assume that $x(t)$ is never zero. The reason for this is that $x \equiv 0$ is an invariant manifold for this system and since RHS of the system is (at least) $C^2$ the existence-uniqueness theorem works here. Hence, no trajectory that started outside of this invariant manifold can join or intersect it. The same is true for $y \equiv 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that $x(t),y(t)$ remain positive, we obtain, as in the answer of  John Wayland Bales, that $y(t)=cx(t)$, for some $c>0$ - In fact, $c=y_0/x_0$ - Also, $x$ satisfies the IVP
$$
x'=x-(1+c)x^2, \quad x(0)=x_0.
$$
The above IVP possesses a unique solution $\varphi(t)$, which is positive (not hard to show) and is defined for all $t>0$. Hence, the vector $\big(\varphi(t), c\varphi(t)\big)$ is *a* solution of the IVP
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
x'=-x^2-xy+x,\\
y'=-y^2-xy+y,
\end{cases} \qquad x(0)=x_0,\quad y(0)=y_0.
\end{equation}
As the above IVP enjoys global uniqueness (it possesses a Lipschitz flux), then $\big(\varphi(t), c\varphi(t)\big)$ is *the unique* solution, it is positive and defined for all $t\ge 0$.

Note also that
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty} x(t)=\frac{1}{1+c}=\frac{x_0}{x_0+y_0}, \quad
\lim_{t\to\infty} x(t)=\frac{y_0}{x_0+y_0}.
$$

Comment: Global uniqueness. Thanks for the rescue.